# How To Add more Frame Like Nexus 6P,5X etc in Screenshots in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, screenshot

I am true Lover of Android studio...

There is one awesome plugin inside Android monitor is **SCHREEN CAPTURE**
as like below image.

[image]

Its great to capture emulator screen.

### My Question

In screen capture there is one option Frame screenshot 
and i can select device for frame of my screen shot.

But there is only 4 device list

- nexus s
- nexus one
- generic phone
- generic tablet

How to add more device frame.

Is there any way?

Waiting for your suggestion.

[image]

### Edited

> NOTE: i dont want xml screenshots from preview tab because its not runtime screen.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826578/9699634

Answer (score 17):

The depends on the device resolution.

If you are trying to capture screenshot on an emulator with **768x1280** resolution, it will show you devices with that resolution (eg. **nexus 4, nexus s, etc.**), where as if you are running an emulator with **1080x1920** resolution, it will show you devices with that resolution (eg. **nexus 5, nexus 5x, etc**.)

Comment: my sdk fully updated, my device resolution is  1080x1920
i think nexes 4 and nexus s have 768*1280 resolutoion .

Comment: and my emulator is nexus5

Comment: You  are right but my que is there is any way to add frame with  any resolution??

Answer (score 7):

Works on mac:  (Should be something similar on windows or linux too)

Find **device-art-resources** folder in Android studio installation location/contents.

Path:
*/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources*

Edit : 
Create your folder with any custom frame you need. 
Edit **device-art.xml** as you need

I just edited Generic Phone text to make sure it works..

[image]

Comment: what is it you dont find.? what OS are you on? ubuntu ?

Comment: ohk its in hide mode

Comment: This doesn't even clearly answer the question! What did you achieve by renaming ? If possible, answer that how to add a N6P image in device screenshot editing window.

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS only, when your emulator is running hit `Command + Shift + 5` and click the emulator window. This will take the screenshot of the frame and the screen. You may need to remove the toolbar window which is also included in the screenshot using an image editor.

Answer (score 1):

Hello according to me i found a

[android asset studio Link](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/device-art-generator)

Have a look at image below:-

[image]

And for getting all the devices listed for frame capture have a look at below image {**If** your wanted device is **listed** in you can find}: -

[image]

Also have a look at [https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/device-art-generator](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html)

Comment: not like that. i am trying to add fram in screenshot not at xml file
thanks for your suggetion

Comment: That link is dead now!

Answer (score 1):

This might be late to ans but I don't think android studio allow for custom frames.

You can change frame online by using this [link](http://picapp.net/), where you can find different types of devices with different styles.

Comment: Paid service. Resolution for free download: 231x530px + watermark. Useless.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hi go to your XML ex:sample_activity.xml(file for which your going take a screen shot)  ->there you select->design on the top left you will get all the devices .

when your right click to save screen, based on the device you will get selected related devices will appear .
enter image description here
[image]

Comment: But this is a layout snapshot, not a real screenshot.

Comment: yes this are layout snapshot only,because we get more optional  virtual devices na.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your SDK first (build tools, platform tools, latest API 23), then update your Android Studio version from the Help menu. It should appear now.

Comment: Looks like you are using Ubuntu. Can you check in the preferences if your SDK path is correct? Android Studio comes with its own SDK, so if you installed the SDK separately, it could be looking at its own bundled SDK instead of your downloaded one.

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work, try to download a beta version, from the Update dialog, go ti Update settings, then choose Canary or Beta update channel. If that also doesn't work then you might be looking at downloading a new Android studio package (a clean install)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure about this but I guess Android Studio shows list of devices according to the size of screenshot as for me it's showing **Nexus 5X for my Nexus 5 connected**.

Anyways go ahead and **update your SDK and Android Studio** to get the frame of at least for Nexus 5X. I'll try to find of Nexus 6P though.

Comment: @VishalPatel Then it's surely according to the size of the screenshot which means size of device connected.

Comment: @VishalPatel We could if the size of screenshot was appropriate. For example you can't fit a 1080p screenshot into larger resolution device frame like of Nexus 6P

Comment: i understand bro but suppose i want frame which have no real resolution of my screenshot  then??  thats what i am said

Comment: @VishalPatel I understand your issue. I'll try to find something for it